# Initializing class with leftovers

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure how this two different codes work, and where is the difference about them.
The problem is that in both codes I have an 
`Entity e` which has no constructor made by myself(so it uses the default one). As I presume, class members X,Y should be allocated in memory but not initialised. In example 1, both variables are set to 0 but in example 2 are just leftovers.
So, why is this happening?

Example 1.

```
int main() {

    unsigned int a = 65664;//int son 4 bytes
    unsigned short* ptr1 = (unsigned short*)&a;

    LOG("---------------------------------------------")

    Entity e;
    std::cout << e.X << std::endl;

    e.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Example 2.

```
int main() {

    LOG("---------------------------------------------")

    Entity e;
    std::cout << e.X << std::endl;

    e.print();

    return 0;
}
```

I leave header and cpp files just in case:

Header:

```
#ifndef THECHERNO_ENTITY_H
#define THECHERNO_ENTITY_H


class Entity {

public:
    float X,Y;


    //Entity();

    void print();

};

#endif //THECHERNO_ENTITY_H
```

Cpp:

```
#include "Entity.h"


void Entity::print() {
        std::cout << X << ", " << Y << std::endl;
}


/*
  Entity::Entity() {
    X = 1;
    Y = 1;
}
 */
```

Comment: I would assume, it's just undefined behaviour?

Comment: Welcome to undefined behavior land.  You can't read from an uninitialized variable.

Comment: [*Undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Uninitialized variables (which the `e` members will be) will have an *indeterminate* value, and using them in almost any way (including reading their indeterminate values) lead to UB.

Comment: Thanks, I won't trouble about this so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class member variables are *default initialized* if there is no explicit initialization.

For *float* (same as integers and pointers) this means "not initialized". So X and Y are in effect left uninitialized (global variables are exception but it does not apply here).

Accessing uninitialized variables is *Undefined behaviour*, in other words anything might happen, not limited to printing of garbage values.

We could speculate what happens at assembly level, but it is generally not useful, especially without the actual assembly code and memory dump at runtime.

Comment: The default initialisation is just grabbing a space of memory, correct?

Comment: @MatiEzelQ The default initialization for primitive types is that, yes. For classes, the constructor is run (but if you have these primitive types as member variables, and don't initialize them, then they will still be left uninitialized by their default initialization). As if it has a space in memory yet... It might or it might not. If you never use it, the compiler might even optimize it out so that it never *really* exist. If it's a local variable it might be in a CPU register. But if you ask for its address, then it will have a space in memory so you get the right address.